# Kendo Angular Grid Responsive Design

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo for Angular and would like to improve the responsiveness of my app on smaller screens.  I have found [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/how-to/render-cells-as-listview/) which describes how to make items a listview.  I also found [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/responsive/) that tells how to hide columns on smaller screens.

Those are both ok, but really what I would like to do is to have all columns on larger screens, but when the screen is small enough to where the grid isn't really readable or effective anymore, switch to the list view where it can display 'cards' of the individual items and their properties vertically.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure why the downvote, but in case anyone else comes across this here is what I ended up doing.

Basically as far as I can figure out you have to create 2 grids to do this and have visibility settings based on media size in css.  I Basically put in both grids from the two links in the question and then made 2 classes called `smallGridContent` and `largeGridContent`.  Small is the small screen display (list view) and large is the large screen display (full grid).  Then I made these css rules to swap them via visibility at 1000px screen width:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .smallGridContent{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .largeGridContent{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Not sure if it's the cleanest or best way to do it but it's working for me.  If anyone has a better solution I would be happy to accept that answer.